# Acumulador solo funciona sobre un solo scope y variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Intentando guardar en diferentes variables, y mostrar en diferentes scope, una sumatoria la cual depende del síntoma que tenga el paciente, solo guarda y muestra en un único scope y una misma variable.

El código es el siguiente:

### index.js

```
<div ng-controller="diagnosticos">

            <ul class="list-borderless">

                <div class="item item-divider">Sintomas principales</div>

                <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">

                    Vive o procede de zonas endemicas

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.uno" ng-change="Sumatoria('uno')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle">

                    Fiebre

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.dos" ng-change="Sumatoria('dos')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

            </ul>

            <ul class="list-borderless" ng-hide="Resultado < 2">

                <div class="item item-divider">Sintomas secundarios</div>

                <li class="item item-toggle">

                    Malestar general

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.tres" ng-change="Sumatoria('tres')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle">

                    Anorexia

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.cuatro" ng-change="Sumatoria('cuatro')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle">

                    Nauseas

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.cinco" ng-change="Sumatoria('cinco')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">

                    Dolor (Muscular, articular, cefalea, etc)

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.seis" ng-change="Sumatoria('seis')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">

                    Rash

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.siete" ng-change="Sumatoria('siete')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">

                    Leucopenia

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.ocho" ng-change="Sumatoria('ocho')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

                <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">

                    Prueba de torniquete positivo

                    <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.nueve" ng-change="Sumatoria('nueve')">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>

                </li>

            </ul>






            <div class="list-borderless">
                <div class="item item-body">
                    <label>Diagnosticos elegidos</label>
                    <h3 class="title">Principales:{{Resultado}}</h3>
                    <h3 class="title">Secundarios:{{Respuesta}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

### Diagnosticos_1.js

```
angular.module('saludApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('diagnosticos', diagnosticos);

diagnosticos.$inject = ['$scope'];

function diagnosticos($scope) {

var SumaDiag, SumaPrincipales, SumaSecundaria;

SumaDiag = 0;
SumaPrincipales = 0;
SumaSecundaria = 0;

$scope.Resultado = SumaDiag;
$scope.Respuesta = SumaDiag;

$scope.principal = {};

$scope.Sumatoria = function(key) {

    if ($scope.principal[key] === true) {

        if (key ? 'uno' : 'dos') {
            SumaPrincipales = SumaPrincipales + 1;
            console.log('La suma primaria' + " " + SumaPrincipales);
            $scope.Resultado = SumaPrincipales;
        } else {
            SumaSecundarios = SumaSecundarios + 1;
            console.log('La suma Secundaria' + " " + SumaSecundarios);
            $scope.Respuesta = SumaSecundaria;
        }

    } else {

        if (key ? 'uno' : 'dos') {
            SumaPrincipales = SumaPrincipales - 1;
            console.log('La resta primaria' + " " + SumaPrincipales);
            $scope.Resultado = SumaPrincipales;
        } else {
            SumaSecundarios = SumaSecundarios - 1;
            console.log('La resta secundaria' + " " + SumaSecundarios);
            $scope.Respuesta = SumaSecundaria;
        }

    };

}

}
```

En la siguiente imagen, se ve como están activos tres toggles de síntomas secundarios, por ende la suma debe ser la secundaria, y debe ser mostrada a través del correspondiente scope, pero esto no sucede.

[image: appsalud]

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Cada controller es creado con un sólo *$scope* y tu tienes un sólo controller en tu código. Creo que lo que intentaste decir es que tienes varias propiedades en tu *$scope*. Es cierto?

Comment: Si @devconcept, entonces, ese puede ser el error??

Comment: Sip. Lo que no veo es que es lo que llamas síntoma primario pues en la vista que muestras todos son secundarios. Donde encuantras los primarios?

Comment: Ya edito y coloco el html, dame un momento.

Comment: Ya esta editado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código puede simplificarse mucho si sigues usando el principio de usar dinámicamente las propiedades del *$scope*. Ya que divides las sumatorias en `principal` y `secundario` debes tener también los resultados divididos de esa misma forma. Repasando, si antes hacías

```
$scope[key] //.... operaciones
```

Ahora puedes hacer

```
$scope[target][key] //.... operaciones
```

Que se traduce al final en

```
$scope.principal.uno
```

Puedes aplicar lo mismo para los resultados y tener

```
$scope.resultados[target] -> $scope.resultados.principal // aqui almacenas las diferentes sumatorias separadas.
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando. Fíjate en lo pequeño que queda tu controller escribiendo el código de esta forma.

```js
angular.module('saludApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('diagnosticos', diagnosticos);

diagnosticos.$inject = ['$scope'];

function diagnosticos($scope) {

  $scope.principal = {};
  $scope.secundario = {};

  $scope.resultado = {
    principal: 0,
    secundario: 0
  };

  $scope.Sumatoria = function(target, key) {
    console.log(target, key);
    if ($scope[target][key] === true) {
      $scope.resultado[target] = $scope.resultado[target] + 1;
    } else {
      $scope.resultado[target] = $scope.resultado[target] - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="saludApp" ng-controller="diagnosticos">
  <ul class="list-borderless">
    <div class="item item-divider">Sintomas principales</div>
    <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">
      Vive o procede de zonas endemicas
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.uno" ng-change="Sumatoria('principal', 'uno')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle">
      Fiebre
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="principal.dos" ng-change="Sumatoria('principal', 'dos')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-borderless" ng-hide="Resultado < 2">
    <div class="item item-divider">Sintomas secundarios</div>
    <li class="item item-toggle">
      Malestar general
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.uno" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'uno')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle">
      Anorexia
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.dos" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'dos')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle">
      Nauseas
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.tres" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'tres')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">
      Dolor (Muscular, articular, cefalea, etc)
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.cuatro" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'cuatro')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">
      Rash
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.cinco" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'cinco')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">
      Leucopenia
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.seis" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'seis')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item item-toggle item-text-wrap">
      Prueba de torniquete positivo
      <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="secundario.siete" ng-change="Sumatoria('secundario', 'siete')">
        <div class="track">
          <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="list-borderless">
    <div class="item item-body">
      <label>Diagnosticos elegidos</label>
      <h3 class="title">Principales:{{resultado.principal}}</h3>
      <h3 class="title">Secundarios:{{resultado.secundario}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, excelente como siempre