# Preguntas múltiples con única respuesta en angular (ionic), problema con selección por pregunta

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy intentando realizar una especie de quiz de tipo opción múltiple con única respuesta.
Cargo la pregunta y sus opciones (respuestas) con datos REST.

Así es como debería verse la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cada pregunta (header en negrilla) debe haber una lista de preguntas (4 preguntas) y debo poder seleccionar al menos una opción en cada pregunta.

Actualmente, no puedo lograrlo en la app en ionic en la que trabajo, sólo me deja seleccionar una respuesta de entre todas las preguntas del test y cuando selecciono otra, se des-selecciona la que había seleccionado, aún estando en otra pregunta...:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el código de la vista y controlador:

**controllers.js**

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.questions.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.questions[i].opcion_multiple == 'si') {
    $scope.multiple = true;
    $scope.multiple_questions[i] = {
      id: $scope.questions[i].id_pregunta,
      question: $scope.questions[i].nombre,
      options: [
        $scope.questions[i].opcion_a,
        $scope.questions[i].opcion_b,
        $scope.questions[i].opcion_c,
        $scope.questions[i].opcion_d
      ],
      option_value: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    };
  }
}
```

**test.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Evaluación">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-repeat="multiple_question in multiple_questions">
      <ion-item>
        <h3 ng-bind-html="multiple_question.question">
          {{multiple_question.question}}
        </h3>
          <ion-radio ng-repeat="option in multiple_question.options"
          ng-model="multiple_question.id"
          ng-value="multiple_question.option_value[$index]">{{option}}</ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**EDIT:** No he sabido... qué valor darle al ng-model para este tipo de aplicación

Comment: Bueno entiendo lo que quieres decir, y aunque trabaje angular e ionic aun  estoy nuevo al ver ciertos codigos, mira este ejemplo, hice una pregunta, por lo que veo es que no estas independizando cada lista, mira este ejemplo [una pregunta que hice](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10783/acumulador-solo-funciona-sobre-un-solo-scope-y-variable)

Comment: Igual estoy preparando una respuesta, dame un segundo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por fin pude resolver este problema. La solución está en el uso de `<ion-list>` y `<ion-item>` (Es decir, no utilizarlas...)

Por alguna razón (que aún investigo...), al usar esas etiquetas, no podia seleccionar una respuesta por pregunta, sino una de entre el total de preguntas de la vista.

Finalmente opté por el uso de etiquetas `<ul>` y `<li>`

El código que tengo en la vista y con el cuál funciona es:

**test.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Evaluación">
  <ion-content>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="question in questions">
        <h3 ng-bind-html="question.questionText " >{{ question.questionText }}</h3>
        <h4>Selección: {{data[$index]}}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
            <ion-radio ng-model="data[$parent.$index]" ng-value="answer"
              name="quest_{{$parent.$index}}_answers" >
              {{ answer }}
            </ion-radio>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me alegra mucho, algo me decia ue aprte de ng-value, era algo asi, por que a mi me paso con los ion-item, en mi proyecto, espero sigas adelante, de antemano pregunto, es algun proyecto personal, o de tus estudios.

Comment: Gracias :)
Es un proyecto de un semillero de investigación de la Universidad.

Answer (score 1):

Ya analice un poco tu pregunta, y con lo que pude ver entre tu pregunta y el ejemplo que está en la página de ionic que lo replique en un plnkr, es que al menos, estas usando un mismo value para todas tus opciones, ya que veo que en **ng-value** colocas  `ng-value="a"`, y como el ejemplo que da la misma documentación en ionic.

Tampoco ve como viene tu objeto del servidor, de igual forma te dejo el ejemplo de la documentación por aquí, para que lo analices, ya que el único error que veo es que estas usando un mismo ***value*** para todo.

[Ejemplo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPMIjeZ3uYZzfQLpymZW?p=preview)

```
$scope.clientSideList = [
{ text: "Backbone", value: "bb" },
{ text: "Angular", value: "ng" },
{ text: "Ember", value: "em" },
{ text: "Knockout", value: "ko" }
]; 

 $scope.serverSideList = [
    { text: "Go", value: "go" },
    { text: "Python", value: "py" },
    { text: "Ruby", value: "rb" },
    { text: "Java", value: "jv" }
  ];
```

Comment: Ese ejemplo ya lo había visto. Justamente cometí el error de dejar `ng-value='a'` debido a que estaba haciendo unas pruebas y olvidé cambiarlo.
Acabo de actualizar la pregunta. Necesito que se lean los valores a, b, c y d para cada preguntar, así que creé un array y le asigno el valor a cada radio input.
Miraré nuevamente el ejemplo que colocaste para intentar hayar la solución.
Aquí otro en el que me estaba fijando...: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqMqO1?p=preview

Comment: Bueno me alegra que te alla servido lo que te comente, de igual forma, ya vi el ejemplo que pusiste, esta bien

Comment: Aún no lo logro hacer funcionar como debe....
Dejando el ng-value como lo dejé al editar la pregunta...
No sé qué más pueda ser :/
Mirando otros ejemplos... en teoría debería funcionar, he probado cambiando el np-repeat de lugar (con etiquetas más externas o internas) y nada :(

Comment: @roadev puse la pregunta en el chat, alli hay alguien que siempre sabe, esperemos que aparezca hoy por aqui, el seguro te dara una mano, seguro que si, de igual forma aqui te dejo el enlace del chat, [enace del chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: Aparentemente es por la iteración de las diferentes preguntas, ya que agarra las preguntas y respuesta del mismo arreglo pero en diferente posición... Según ese ejemplo que colocaste, ellos consumen de dos arrays diferentes.

Comment: Pero aun no has podido??

Comment: Nada..., intenté armar el array de varias maneras siguiendo los dos ejemplos aquí publicados...
Pareciera que el <ion-radio> no deja iterar de esa manera para separar las preguntas.

Comment: por que no intentas usar `div` y `class`

Comment: ¿Qué propones?
He intentado hasta con listas (no de ionic) siguiendo uno de los ejemplos...

Comment: Usando input tipo radio me funcionó replicando el ejemplo del quiz...
Entonces sí es por el tipo de etiqueta :/
Tocará darle estilos o ahondar más en ello.

Comment: Ya pude... postearé la solución
Lo que menos pensé... tiene que ver con las etiquetas <ion-list> y <ion-item>